# Deriving the continued fraction for Pi

Tags: pi, continued-fractions

So I was searching online for methods to approximate Pi and found [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z81On.jpg)
continued fraction that supposedly approximates to Pi when continued infinitely. I've tried searching all over the internet for how this was derived or why this works but could only find something similar but not close enough. I've got some basic knowledge of continued fractions but do not have experience with numbers that change throughout, how would one derive this equation? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try  [this paper](https://maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/pubs/amm_supplements/Monthly_Reference_11.pdf), whose subject is precisely this identity, and which gives a proof of it.